# Date not properly showing as per example

Tags: office-js

i have used sample demo like below code
var Table = sheet.tables.add("A1:D1", true);
Table.getHeaderRowRange().values = [["Date", "Merchant", "Category", "Amount"]];

```
                                                Table.rows.add(null /*add rows to the end of the table*/, [
                                                    ["1/1/2017", "The Phone Company", "Communications", "$120"],
                                                    ["1/2/2017", "Northwind Electric Cars", "Transportation", "$142"],
                                                    ["1/5/2017", "Best For You Organics Company", "Groceries", "$27"],
                                                    ["1/10/2017", "Coho Vineyard", "Restaurant", "$33"],
                                                    ["1/11/2017", "Bellows College", "Education", "$350"],
                                                    ["1/15/2017", "Trey Research", "Other", "$135"],
                                                    ["1/15/2017", "Best For You Organics Company", "Groceries", "$97"]
                                                ]);
```

but Out put was different showing me please check on image attachment
second row i have used date in json data : 1/2/2017
but on excel sheet it show me like: 02/01/2017
so please help me regrading this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpGY0.png)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you current region format setting for date time is: `dd/mm/yyyy`.

In Excel JS API, We use `mm/dd/yyyy`  or `yyyy/mm/dddd` as date format. So your input will be recognized as `mm/dd/yyyy`, that's why it shows 02/01/2017.

In this sample, author's intention is creating a table with date format as `mm/dd/yyyy`, in your current region it shows your date format `dd/mm/yyyy`, but if you change your region to US, then It will show the `mm/dd/yyyy`.